# How to use weighted vote for classification using weka

Tags: classification, weka, vote, weighted

I know we can use the vote classifier to combine different classifiers.

May I know if there is any way to combine the classifiers with different weights for each classifier? How would I be able to do that with Weka?

I have googled that we can add weights to attributes or instances. But I would like to know how to add weight to classifiers.

If weighted vote is not possible, is there any other way I can do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It does not appear possible to achieve weighted voting with Weka without modifying the Java classes yourself.

- [Source 1](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/weighted-Vote-classifier-td26174.html)
- [Source 2](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Weighted-voting-td7489.html)

That being said, **I believe you can achieve rudimentary weighting by providing multiples of the base classifiers to the voting meta classifier**. This appears to be backed up by the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/classifiers/meta/Vote.java#Vote.buildClassifier%28weka.core.Instances%29).

> For example:
>
> Classifier 1: J48 decision tree
>   Classifier 2: J48 decision tree
>   Classifier 3: naive Bayes

This would allow the decision tree to vote twice and therefore have a higher weight than naive Bayes.